# Unknown error in iolo system mechanic

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I was using [system mechanic](http://www.iolo.com/products/system-mechanic/) which is not working properly it gives an "**unknown error**". I have tried to uninstall and re-install , tried to remove it completely from registry , tried to re-install it in another user account same issue, i am using windows 7, but i have a friend who used windows xp and getting the same error. How to identify why exactly it shows this error. Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Is it a paid registered version?

Comment: don't use such tools which only cause more errors compared to what they fix/improve.

Comment: it is a paid version.

Answer (score 1):

For starter you can look at Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application. It should give you more details about error itself.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Internet Explorer 11 and System Mechanic works fine now.

Comment: IE 11 wasn't released for Windows 7 when the OP asked his question (and was never released for Windows XP) , so I don't think this answer applies to the question.

Comment: Also had this problem with IE 10 but not with IE 9